# Can I force cmake to include my header file in specific targets?

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, c-preprocessor

I have a header file which overrides malloc with a macro. Using `add_definitions(-include ../include/failing-malloc-test.h)` I'm able to force cmake to include this header file in all targets. The problem is that I only want to have my header file included in some targets(test targets and so on). I tried achieving this using `target_compile_definition`, but I couldn't achieve the same effect, because `target_compile_definition` seems to work different than `add_definitions`. Currently the only solution that I can think of is duplicating all source files and adding the `#include "failing-malloc-test.h"` manually - what I obviously want to avoid doing.

Comment: Have you tried adding [properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-source-files) to the specific source files?  Specifically, the `COMPILE_FLAGS`.

Comment: No, I didn't knew about that one. I'm pretty new to cmake. I will take a look at this, thanks.

Comment: Using `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (main PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS
    "-include ../include/failing-malloc-test.h")` I have solved my problem! Thanks for hinting me to the properties stuff! If you want go ahead and post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Consider to use `target_compile_options` instead of `target_compile_definitions` -- this is the "modern" way to solve your issue.

Comment: Related but not the same: [cmake include header into every source file](/q/32773283/11107541).

Answer (score 2):

CMake has a properties-based mechanism.  You can assign to properties on targets, source files, and other parts.  Working with targets is the usual and default action, so a whole family of `target_*` commands are provided for setting properties on targets.  If you want to add a compile option for all sources in a specific target then use [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html).  Do not use the [`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) property for other options than defining pre-processor symbols.  So you be able to get what you want with

```
target_compile_options(<my-test-target> "-include ../include/failing-malloc-test.h")
```

Comment: And of course this will only work on toolchains supporting the `-include` option, essentially rendering your build non-portable. Be mindful of this!