# How to force include header in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am porting project from Makefile to cmake. There is a CFLAG/CXXFLAG in Makefile `-include "SystemTest.h"`. I tried to add this to my toolchain file directly to `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` but then test compilation fails because it cannot find `SystemTest.h`.

I searched and found answers like these: [Can I force cmake to include my header file in specific targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322670/can-i-force-cmake-to-include-my-header-file-in-specific-targets) and [cmake include header into every source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773283/cmake-include-header-into-every-source-file) which looked promising but didn't work for me.

Here are the lines where I use add_executable. Commented code is what I already tried:

```
add_executable(my_target ${SRC})
if (WIN32)
  target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE module_a module_b module_c module_d module_e module_f)
elseif(UNIX)
  target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE module_a module_b module_c module_d module_e module_f ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
else(WIN32)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Not supported OS.")
endif(WIN32)

# set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -include SystemTest.h")
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -include SystemTest.h")

# add_definitions(-include SystemTest.h)

# target_compile_definitions(cherrySim_runner
#   PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:-include SystemTest.h>
#           $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-include SystemTest.h>
# )

# target_compile_definitions(cherrySim_runner "-include SystemTest.h")
```

CMake/gcc fails when compiling files from `module_b` complaining about stuff that should come from `SystemTest.h`.

Comment: When you use `-include SystemTest.h` the compiler adds `#include "SystemTest.h"` to the top of every source file. Since it's included using quotes instead of angle-brackets `<>`, the file must be either in the same directory as the source file, or in the standard include directory search path. You can of course provide a full path to the header file, which you might want to try first.

Comment: The problem is `SystemTest.h` has more dependencies. But it might be a way for a workaround.

Comment: You should add the directory where `SystemTest.h` is located with `target_include_directories` together with your `CMAKE_C/CXX_FLAGS -include SystemTest.h`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the solutions in the questions you linked are not suitable for you?